# Error while upgrading spring-boot version of application to 2.6.9 : Application not starting up

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to upgrade spring boot version of a multi-module application. I am getting error:  "Error creating bean with name 'registrationListener'"

New spring-boot-parent version:2.6.9

New spring-cloud version : 2021.0.3

New de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-dependencies version : 2.6.8

I am getting the following error:

```
Channel 'abc.errorChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
stopped bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'registrationListener': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:220) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.getTargetBean(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:371) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:336) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:229) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:166) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:427) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1058) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1021) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1652) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.destroy(DefaultBinderFactory.java:120) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:559) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1163) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:520) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1156) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1106) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:596) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.9.jar:2.6.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:745) ~[spring-boot-2.6.9.jar:2.6.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:420) ~[spring-boot-2.6.9.jar:2.6.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.6.9.jar:2.6.9]
    at com.abc.de.MainApplication.main(DTCmsApplication.java:52) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.9.jar:2.6.9]
```

registrationListener is present in class SpringBootAdminClientAutoConfiguration of spring-boot-admin-client:2.6.8

Can someone help with this? Am I using wrong version combinations

Comment: That's a very old version of Spring Boot.  We're up to 3.0.3 today.  It requires JDK 17.  I'd suggest you think about making that jump as soon as you can.  Even if you don't, you should be using 2.7.9.

Comment: Hi, I am bound to use JDK 8 for my project. I tried to run same project with 2.7.9 spring-boot-starter-parent. But, still same error is coming up!

Comment: You should upgrade JDK 8, too.  It's already past the end of its support life.  You are asking for trouble.

Comment: Hi @duffymo, I tried to upgrade JDK to 17. Still I am getting same error. My spring boot parent version is 2.7.9, spring-cloud version is 2021.0.6, spring-admin version is 2.7.10. Please suggest what can be done

Comment: You are not bound to JDK 8, as you said.  Spring Boot 3.0.4 is my next recommendation.  Spring Cloud should be 2022.0.1. 
 You'll be up to date then.   Once that's done, you can start to fix your problems. 
 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-parent/2022.0.1